# Freeing connections and commands with using

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

When both a SqlConnection and a SqlCommand are created in a single using block, are both freed on exit, or are nested using blocks necessary?

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString).CreateCommand()) {

    // Use command..
}
```

Comment: Yes you need using block on both. A using block is for that object only NOT the other objects that might be created inside. What you have here would only dispose of the command, the connection would get left stranded.

Comment: Yes, you need `using` on the connection, the command, any transactions, any data-readers, etc. However: I *strongly* recommend deferring all this ugliness to a tool such as [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/), which makes it *much* easier to work effectively with ADO.NET (and it is free); for examples, see [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Readme.md)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `using` block just calls `.Dispose()` on the resource that you declare once the block is finished executing.

[MSDN: The Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement)

So, yes, you should wrap both the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` in a `using` statement to ensure that both of these resources are properly disposed.

EDIT: You can also stack `using` commands like so:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("command", connection)) {
       // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most important part is disposing the `SqlConnection` object, with the help of the `using` statement preferably. So following your example, this would be the appropriate way of doing that:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    cn.Open();

    using (var command = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        // Use command..
    }
}
```

Behind the scenes this is what the `using` statement translates into, you can appreciate how it helps to reduce boilerplate:

```
{
    var cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    try
    {
        cn.Open();

        {
            var command = cn.CreateCommand();

            try
            {
                // Use command..
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

By disposing the `SqlConnection` instance with the `using` statement you can be sure that the connection will be closed after leaving the scope, even if an exception occurs.